# Parse substring from a string that starts with specific word

Tags: php, string, substring, string-parsing

I have a mutli-line string `$comment`, which looks like:

```
@Description: some description.
@Feature/UseCase: some features.
@InputParameter: some input param.
@ChangedParameter: some changed param.
@NewOutputParameter: some output param.
@Comments/Note: some notes.
```

I want to convert it into six different strings so that after the conversion it should look like: `$description = 'some description'`, `$features = 'some features'` and so on. How can I achieve that?

I have tried [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), but it's not working for me. I'm a beginner in PHP and would appreciate any help.

Comment: is `$comment` just a variable containing multiline text?

Comment: yes. actually I have an array `$comments` of `$comment`, where each `$comment` looks like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode` twice, one with the `@` separator to get the fields and then with the `:` separator to get each field content...

```
$fields = explode("@",$comment);

$description = trim(explode(":",$fields[1])[1]);
$features = trim(explode(":",$fields[2])[1]);
$inputparameter = trim(explode(":",$fields[3])[1]);
....
```

You can simplify it a little bit using the `array_map` function to get the field content...

```
$fields = array_slice(explode("@",$comment),1);
$fieldcontents = array_map(function($v) { return trim(explode(":",$v)[1]); }, $fields);

$description = $fieldcontents[0];
$features = $fieldcontents[1];
$inputparameter = $fieldcontents[2];
....
```

Comment: Hi, your first solution is working for me. Thanks. But the second solution is giving a notice `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in return trim(explode(":",$v)[1]);`

Comment: Yes, it's because of the first element of the `$fields` array (`$fields[0]`), which is empty because your string starts with a `@`. When the `array_map` deal with that first position, it doesn't have the `:` character so the explode returns one element and the [1] doesn't exist, and give you a notice. Anyway, if you want to remove that element so the notice don't appear, just change the first line for `$fields = array_slice(explode("@",$comment),1);` and then you can start the `$fieldcontents` in the zero index. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `preg_replace`, `explode` and `list` functions:

```
$comment = '
    @Description: some description.
    @Feature/UseCase: some features.
    @InputParameter: some input param.
    @ChangedParameter: some changed param.
    @NewOutputParameter: some output param.
    @Comments/Note: some notes.';

list($description, $feature, $input_param, $changed_param, $new_param, $note) = 
    explode('.', preg_replace('/\s*@[^:]+:\s*([^.]+.)/', '$1', $comment));

var_dump($description, $feature, $input_param, $changed_param, $new_param, $note);
```

The output (for all variables created):

```
string(16) "some description"
string(13) "some features"
string(16) "some input param"
string(18) "some changed param"
string(17) "some output param"
string(10) "some notes"
```